# Adding style to border to have shadow right or bottom

Tags: html, css

I know how to make shadow around for a table or an image. Is there a way to make shadow for border as well? This is my table cell CSS. Thank you!

```
.customerCell{
    color: #000000;
    background:#f4f2e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This is the example of the border I'm talking about.

[image: Example of the borders]

Comment: what do you mean by border? the sides of the div?

Comment: border for the td cell. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you are you wanting this: [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/vdGjs/)

**CSS:**

```
.customerCell{
    color: #000000;
    background:#f4f2e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px #eee;
}
```

Use the CSS3 `box-shadow` property. It's parmeters are like this:

```
box-shadow: horizontal-offset vertical-offset blur spread color inset;
```

So in your case:

**`horizontal-offset`**: 3px

**`vertical-offset`**: 3px

**`blur`**: 2px

**`spread`**: 0px

**`color`**: #eee